# how to populate class/model with JSON data in angular2

Tags: json, angular

I have a json data which is coming from service but currently i have created a mock json data.
Requirement : I want to populate this data into my class. Could someone suggest how the architecture of class should be and how to populate/map the data from JSON to class.

JSON Data

```
export const Data =
{
    "elements": [
        {
            "name": "stringVal",
            "facets": [
                {
                    "name": "Cameras",
                    "link": {
                        "type": "Link",
                        "uri": 
                    },
                    "hits": {
                        "type": "Link",
                        "uri": 
                    },
                    "selected": true
                },
                {
                    "name": "Cameras2",
                    "link": {
                        "type": "Link2",
                        "uri": 
                    },
                    "hits": {
                        "type": "Link2",
                        "uri": 
                    },
                    "selected": false
                },

            ],
            "displayType": "text_clear",
            "selectionType": "taxonomic",

        },
        {
            "name": "Brand",
            "facets": [
                {
                    "name": "Canon",
                    "link": {
                        "type": "Link",
                        "uri": 
                    },
                    "hits": {
                        "type": "Link",
                        "uri": 
                    },
                    "selected": false
                },
                {
                    "name": "Canon",
                    "link": {
                        "type": "Link",
                        "uri": 
                    },
                    "hits": {
                        "type": "Link",
                        "uri": 
                    },
                    "selected": false
                },
            ],
            "displayType": "text_clear",
            "selectionType": "single",

        },
    ],
    "type": "stringValue",
    "name": "filters"
}
```

Comment: We can see the requirement, so what have you tried and where do you have an issue in your code?

Comment: Can i ask why do you want it in your class , you want to display these values in your template i guess ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create typescript classes :

```js
public class Data {
  type: string;
  name: string;
  elements: ElementItem[];
}

public class ElementItem {
  name: string;
  displayType: string;
  selectionType: string;
  facets: Facet[];
}
public class Facet {
  name: string;
  selected: Boolean;
  link: Link;
  hits: Hit;
}
public class Link {
  type: string;
  uri: string;
}
public class Hit {
  type: string;
  uri: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your model

```
export class YourModel {
    yourProperty: any;
    yourProperty2: any;

    constructor(options: {
        yourProperty: any;
        yourProperty2: any;
    }) {
        this.yourProperty = options.yourProperty;
        this.yourProperty2 = options.yourProperty2;
    } 
}
```

your service

```
@Injectable()
export class YourService {
    getData() {
        return this.http.get('path_to_your_json')
        .map((response) => {
            let result = [];
            response.forEach(object => {
                result.push(new YourModel(object));
            });
            return result;
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export class Person {

    dateOfBirth: Date;
    age: number;
    comments: string[];

    constructor(values: Object = {}) {
        Object.assign(this, values);
    }
}
```